# BluetoothSocket stops transmitting on OutputStream.write()

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a `BluetoothSocket` that is communicating with a custom device (bidirectional). Sometimes (this happens about 1 times out of 4 when transferring 8 Mb data in 300 bytes chunks), in the middle of a file transfer, the Bluetooth stops transmitting data. For about 100-200 chunks of data (I don't have the exact amount), `OutputStream.write(byte[], int, int)` continues to return normally after each calls. There are no exceptions generated. Then after that, the call to `OutputStream.write(byte[], int, int)` locks.

The code was tested on an ASUS eee transformer Pad TF101.

I don't have access to the low `OutputStream` code to see what is happening and to debug. My guess would be that there is a buffer getting filled but not being emptied. When the buffer is full, `write` would lock.

Anyone has an idea what is happening?

Here is the sample code:

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        setName( "BT Connected Thread" );

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.e( "BT GetStreams", e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage( FirmwareHandler.COMMAND_READ, bytes, -1, buffer.clone() ).sendToTarget();

            } catch (IOException e) 
            {
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] buffer, int size) {
        try {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Before Write, size = " + size + ", mmOutStream.toString() = " + mmOutStream.toString() + ", mmSocket..toString() = " + mmSocket.toString());

            mmOutStream.write(buffer, 0, size); // This is the call that locks.
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "After Write");
            mmOutStream.flush(); // Make sure the command is sent entirely immediately
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "After Flush");


        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Once the lock has happen, if I turn off, then turn on the remote <kbd>Bluetooth</kbd> device, the socket unlocks with an IO exception. Then, when I try connecting, back to the <kbd>Bluetooth</kbd> device, I get a `Bluetooth java.IOException:Service discovery failed`. The only way to get the <kbd>Bluetooth</kbd> back is to reboot the tablet.

**EDIT#2:**

If I disconnect the socket manually after there is such lock, it returns without any exception. The connection status of the remote device stays connected. However, if I try to connect to any device (not necessarily the one that locked, even if the device was connected is powered down), I get the following exception:

```
09-13 09:34:45.342: E/BT Connection Assert(1864): Service discovery failed
09-13 09:34:45.342: W/System.err(1864): java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
09-13 09:34:45.342: W/System.err(1864):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:397)
09-13 09:34:45.342: W/System.err(1864):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:207)
09-13 09:34:45.342: W/System.err(1864):     at com.brioconcept.hit001.communication.bluetooth.BluetoothService$ConnectThread.run(BluetoothService.java:177)
```

The only way to recover seems to be to reboot the tablet.

Comment: Can you post your Logcat error? Maybe we can get a clearer picture. And a simple question, have you tried without flush()?

Comment: @Radu There is no error message per say. I get the `Before Write`, `After Write`, `After Flush`, ... for a while, even if the communication is frozen. Then, finally, i get a `Before Write` and nothing else.

Comment: Please try without flush(). Also can you try surrounding both write and flush calls with a try/catch and print the exceptions? Also please treat the exceptions and try to reconnect. This should obviously be implemented. What about the device on the other side? Maybe it crashes - you are sending a lot of data!

Comment: @Radu When the communication freezes, there is no exception, ether for flush or write. I have tried disconnecting manually, `mmSocket.close()` also runs without exception. However, after that, the tablet is not able to connect to any device until it is rebooted.

Comment: Is the remote device actually reading all of the data you're sending? If not, then your situation sounds exactly like a question I recently answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354643/android-bluetoothsocket-outputstream-write-blocks-infinitely/12356666#12356666 While I'm here, I should point out that your read strategy is going to have problems as well. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239692/android-inputstream-dropping-first-two-bytes-modified-bluetoothchat/12288979#12288979

Comment: Another thing. When the connect fails (as discussed in your second edit), try using the reflection method as a fall-back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755068/problems-with-reflection-for-createrfcommsocket After lots of practical experience, my own application tries the reflection method in the first instance.

Comment: @Trevor When everything is going fine, the remote device is reading the data that is written. However, when the communication freezes, I can't see any data being received on the remote device. I was thinking that the issue was with the Android Bluetooth stack since only a reboot on the android side would solve the problem. With your answer to the other question, I will take a closer look at what is happening on the remote side to see if there is a deadlock that prevents me from receiving data.

Comment: If all else fails, I wonder if you can kind of Elastoplast over the problem by only writing a certain sized chunk of data (e.g. 1KiB) each time the remote device has sent an ACK for the last chunk.

Comment: @Trevor That is already what I am doing. I am sending data in chunks of 309 Bytes (300 bytes payload + custom protocol). I am waiting for an Ack from the module before sending the next chunk. If there is no Ack received after a 2 second delay, the chunk of data is re-sent. At some point, I stop receiving Ack. I have probed the remode device and it doesn't see any bluetooth data (no serial communication between a rn-42 bluetooth device and a microcontroller). That is where the buffers get filled with retries and the `writes` finally lock. The initial issue is when I stop receiving acks.

Comment: I re-read the entire thread - are ou using SPP probably? If so, then can you *please* test against another device? Maybe the embedded device is at fault..You can easily set up another bluetooth tool using a cheap bluetooth dongle...No programming required (but if you require it you can use http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/)